# Handyspark Dataframe works on driver or executor

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pyspark

Handyspark dataframe in Pyspark is a bridge between pyspark dataframe and pandas dataframe ,So does it reside on executor node or driver node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HandySpark isn't a "bridge" - it's a wrapper round a Spark DataFrame which gives it a pandas-like API. Therefore it executes on the executors; there would be little point in the project if it executed on the driver as you could always just to `toPandas` on your DataFrame to pull it back to the driver (*don't do this!*)

That all said, HandySpark seems to be abandoned, the last commit being eighteen months ago in May 2019. I'd suggest looking at [Koalas](https://koalas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) instead which does the same thing but is actively developed.

Comment: Thanks, but how can we know which piece of code is on driver and which is executed by executor?